# C++11 constructor inheritance and constructors with no parameters

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++11, constructor

In this piece of code, why is A's constructor with no parameters not inherited? Is there a special rule that prevents inheriting constructors with no parameters?

```
struct A {
    A(void *) {}
    A() {}
};

class B : public A {
public:
    using A::A;
    B(int x) {}
};

void f() {
    B b(1);
    B b2(nullptr);
    B b3; // error
}
```

clang++ -std=c++11 gives this error, and g++ -std=c++11 gives a substantially similar error message:

```
td.cpp:15:7: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'B'
    B b3; // error
      ^
td.cpp:9:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires single argument 'x', but no arguments
      were provided
    B(int x) {}
    ^
td.cpp:8:14: note: candidate constructor (inherited) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 0 were
      provided
    using A::A;
             ^
td.cpp:2:5: note: inherited from here
    A(void *) {}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The relevant information is in 12.9 [class.inhctor] paragraph 3 (the highlighting is added):

> For each non-template constructor in the candidate set of inherited constructors **other than a constructor having no parameters or a copy/move constructor having a single parameter**, a constructor is implicitly declared with the same constructor characteristics unless there is a user-declared constructor with the same signature in the complete class where the using-declaration appears. [...]

That is, default constructor are not inherited unless they have a [defaulted] argument. If they have a default argument they are inherited but without the defaulted argument as is pointed out by a node on the same paragraph:

> Note: Default arguments are not inherited. [...]

Basically, that says that default constructors are not inherited.

Answer (score 0):

there is no constructor in B with no parameters, try

```
B() : A(){}
```

Comment: The question is why isn't the default-constructor of `A` inherited through the statement `using A::A`. This is an obvious albeit irrelevant solution.

Comment: I don't know where you got using A::A from, or if it should work as I think, but in C++ there is no prohibition against inheriting a constructor with no parameters. Even the default constructor of the derived class does that.

Comment: `using A::A` is from the OPs code. If you read the answer above, it explains the problem.