# Constructor inheritance and custom constructors

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++11

Using this hierarchy :

```
struct TestBase {
    // Constructor
    TestBase();
    TestBase(int a);
    TestBase(TestBase const &testBase);

    // Destructor
    virtual ~TestBase();
};

struct TestChild : public TestBase {
    // Constructor inheritance
    using TestBase::TestBase;
};
```

With this test code :

```
TestBase testBase;                  // 1) Custom constructor
TestChild testChild;                // 2) Default constructor created by the compiler
TestChild testChild2(1);            // 3) Inherited from parent with 'using' keyword
TestChild testChild3(testChild);    // 4) Default copy constructor created by the compiler ?
TestChild testChild4(testBase);     // 5) Doesn't work, why it doesn't inherit ?
```

---

First I was thinking that in test 4 the copy constructor was inherited from TestBase (by the 'using' keyword) but in fact it's because the compiler generates a default copy constructor which calls copy constructor of the parent class, is it correct ?

A copy constructor can't be inherited because it must have the same parameter type than the class, is it correct too ?

But why test 5 doesn't compile ? It's not a copy constructor for the TestChild class so it must be inherited, no?

---

This is the error message:

```
foo.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
foo.cpp:21:34: error: no matching function for call to ‘TestChild::TestChild(TestBase&)’
 TestChild testChild4(testBase);     // 5) Doesn't work, why it doesn't inherit ?
                              ^
foo.cpp:21:34: note: candidates are:
foo.cpp:11:12: note: TestChild::TestChild()
     struct TestChild : public TestBase {
            ^
foo.cpp:11:12: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
foo.cpp:13:25: note: TestChild::TestChild(int)
         using TestBase::TestBase;
                         ^
foo.cpp:13:25: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘TestBase’ to ‘int’
foo.cpp:11:12: note: TestChild::TestChild(const TestChild&)
     struct TestChild : public TestBase {
            ^
foo.cpp:11:12: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘TestBase’ to ‘const TestChild&’
foo.cpp:11:12: note: TestChild::TestChild(TestChild&&)
foo.cpp:11:12: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘TestBase’ to ‘TestChild&&’
```

Comment: If you have a compilation error for test 5, then the error message should be part of the question.

Comment: I think it's related to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20435859/c11-constructor-inheritance-and-constructors-with-no-parameters (see accepted answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A *using-declaration* that names a constructor implicitly declares a set of inherited constructors, but what is worth noting is that there are certain constructs which are not inherited.

---

#### What does the standard say?

> 12.9 **Inheriting Constructors** `[class.inhctor]`
>
> > <sup>3</sup> For **each non-template constructor in the candidate set of inherited constructors other than a constructor having no parameters or a copy/move constructor having a single parameter, a constructor is implicitly declared with the same constructor characteristics** unless there is a user-declared constructor with the same signature in the complete class where the *using-declaration* appears or the constructor would be a default, copy ,or move constructor for that class.

The above sentence might look more cryptic that it actually is.. what it is saying, in simple english, is that a constructor is only inherited in the context of `using Base::Base` if the constructor;

- isn't a template, and;
- isn't a default constructor (ie. having no parameters), and;
- isn't a copy/move constructor, and;
- there's no explicit declaration in `Derived` that matches a constructor normally inherited from `Base`

---

#### Conclusion

With the above in mind we realize that the constructor in `TestBase` that takes a `TestBase const&` is a copy-constructor, and since copy-constructors are not inherited, that's the reason for it being non-present in `TestChild`.