# Inheriting constructor and providing new overload: no arguments base constructor seems to not participate in overload resolution

Tags: c++, overloading, c++14, inheriting-constructors

Tests show a strange behavior (`c++14`, `g++ 4.9.1`, `clang 3.5.5`):

To sum it up:

- if `B` provides no other constructors it can use `A::A()`
- if `B` provides other constructors it cannot use `A::A()`, but it uses `A::A(whatever arguments)`, which is unexpected  behavior (to me at least).

---

Setup 1:

```
struct A {
  A() {};
  A(int) {}; // with or without this overload the result are the same
};

struct B : A {
  using A::A;
};

B b0{}; // OK
```

Setup 2:

```
struct A {
  A() {}; // with a default constructor instead (empty class A)
          // the results are the same
};

struct B : A {
  using A::A;
  B(int){}
};

B b0{}; // no matching constructor
B b1{24}; // OK
```

Setup 3:

```
struct A {
  A() {};
  A(int) {};
};

struct B : A {
  using A::A;
  B(int, int){}
};

B b0{}; // no matching constructor
B b1{24}; // OK
B b2{24, 42}; // OK
```

---

Why is this happening and how can it be "fixed".

Comment: The default constructor is special. You can "fix" it e.g. by writing explicitly declaring the default constructor, and defaulting it: `B() = default;` I guess some properties of the default constructor cannot be "reproduced" by an inheriting constructor, such as triviality, hence the special rules.

Comment: Are these the exact examples that you are building with, they don't work or me? Can you provide a live link? i.e [wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/) or [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/)

Comment: @dyp You are right. Why not put you comment into an answer? ;)

Comment: The examples shouldn't be real. For one thing, you're not inheriting anything. Please create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: sry, I typed instead of copying, fixed the inheritance.

Comment: @DanielFrey Because I'm not entirely sure about the rationale. Re-reading the proposal, there seems to be some nontrivial interaction between the rules for inheriting ctors and the implicit generation of ctors. That might as well be the reason for the exceptions (no default, copy, move ctor via inheriting ctors).

Comment: Instead of "the result are the same" please indicate _in the testcase_ what it is that is happening that you do not want to happen (or vice versa). Your question is difficult to parse.

Comment: @DanielFrey Also, duplicates. http://stackoverflow.com/q/20435859 etc.

Comment: bolov, typing is good (you'll need to fix formatting anyhow), but then *copy back* and check your code.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The part in the OP "how can it be fixed" arguably makes it a distinct question, no? (At least you could add that to your answer :) ) -- edit: oops, you did that. also: https://xkcd.com/541/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't tell you the rationale for this, but I can at least tell you that it is standard-mandated:

> `[C++11: 12.9/3]`: For each non-template constructor in the candidate set of inherited constructors **other than a constructor having no parameters** or a copy/move constructor having a single parameter, a constructor is implicitly declared with the same constructor characteristics unless there is a user-declared constructor with the same signature in the class where the *using-declaration* appears. *[..]*

Since the default `B()` invokes the default `A()`, you can "fix" it like this:

```
struct B : A
{
   B() = default;

   using A::A;
   B(int, int){}
};
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e2f30a79ad58a27a))

The following [wording from the original proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2540.htm) (n2540) suggests that this fix's ease and symmetry is more or less the driving factor behind the decision, though I still find that to be somewhat unsatisfactory. Oh well.

> Copy and default constructors are not forwarded, deferring to the existing rules for implicitly declaring copy/default constructors.